# React how to call a function properly to response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a blog using React and MongoDB. I retrieve the data from MongoDB, here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Post extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       posts: []
      };
  }

  truncateText = text => {
    return text.substring(0, 500) + "...";
   }

    allPosts = () => {
      return this.state.posts.map(function(astroPost, i){
        return <div class="post-container">
            <img className="post-info-container__image" src={astroPost.picture} alt=""/>
            <div className="post" posts={astroPost} key={i}>
             <div class="post-container__text">
             <h2>{astroPost.title}</h2>
             <p className="date">{astroPost.date}</p>
             <p className="post-info-container__text">{this.truncateText(astroPost.postContent)}</p>
             <button>Read more</button>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div>
             })
           }

     componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/')
           .then(response => {
               this.setState({posts: response.data})
               console.log(response)
           })
           .catch(function(error) {
               console.log(error)
           })
       }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          { this.allPosts() } 
       </div>
      )
  }
}
```

I want to truncate the text of my post so that a post shows only 500 symbols. I achieved this by doing so:

```
return this.state.posts.map(function(astroPost, i){
        return <div class="post-container">
            <img className="post-info-container__image" src={astroPost.picture} alt=""/>
            <div className="post" posts={astroPost} key={i}>
             <div class="post-container__text">
             <h2>{astroPost.title}</h2>
             <p className="date">{astroPost.date}</p>
             <p className="post-info-container__text">{astroPost.postContent.substring(0, 500) + "..."}</p>
             <button>Read more</button>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div>
```

But I want to do it with a function that get's called on the text, so I kept the same logic in a function called truncateText, but when I call it like this:

```
   return this.state.posts.map(function(astroPost, i){
        return <div class="post-container">
            <img className="post-info-container__image" src={astroPost.picture} alt=""/>
            <div className="post" posts={astroPost} key={i}>
             <div class="post-container__text">
             <h2>{astroPost.title}</h2>
             <p className="date">{astroPost.date}</p>
             <p className="post-info-container__text">{astroPost.postContent.truncateText()}</p>
             <button>Read more</button>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div>
             })
           }
```

It says that `TypeError: astroPost.postContent.truncateText is not a function`

How can I call that function and perform the truncation properly?

Comment: Can you try:  this.truncateText(astroPost.postContent)

Comment: it says that truncateText is undefined, it doesn't work with this too

Comment: Oh duh, you either need to bind the function in your constructor or make it an arrow function.  You can add this.truncateText = this.truncateText.bind(this); in your constructor.  Or you can call the function like:  {() => this.truncateText(astroPost.postContent}}

Answer (score 1):

You have not bound `truncatetext` to the component: [that causes problems with the context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In the constructor, you can use `this.truncatetext = this.truncatetext.bind(this)`:

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       posts: []
      };
      this.truncateText = this.truncateText.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

astroPost is just the element inside the array you are iterating.

Also, if you create a function in your class, you have to do one of this things: or bind the function to the "this" element, or create the function as an arrow function. I recommend second option. So, for your case, you would end with something like this:

```
truncateText = text => {
 return text.substring(0, 500) + "...";
}
```

and then, inside your map you can call it like this:

```
<p className="post-info-container__text">{this.truncateText(astroPost.postContent)}</p>
```

Comment: I changed my function to you suggestion and called it the same way and I now get ```Cannot read property 'truncateText' of undefined```

Comment: because allPosts should be an arrow function too. change it to allPosts = () => {...}

Comment: @MahmaDeva that error is saying that your 'this' instance inside allPosts doesnt know "truncateText". if you make allPosts an arrow function, it has to work. Can you send me the new code? There is something you are making wrong there.

Comment: @MaximilianoPoggioYes I edited my question with the updated code.